# Meaning of "likely" according to ODE?

Tags: meaning

I am having difficulties understanding the (definition of "likely"given by "ODE"):

> LIKELY(Adj.)-such as well might happen or be true

How to understand this definition?

Comment: If something _well might_ or _might well_ happen, it is quite probable (or likely!) that it will happen.

Comment: @KateBunting why it used "such as"??

Comment: _Such as_ is dictionary-speak for 'the kind of thing that...'

Comment: Where is this definition from? I assumed ODE was a typo for OED, but the definition given doesn't match that.

Comment: It;s the oxford languages definition, as used by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About "such as":

The word "likely" is an adjective, so a dictionary's definition must also be an adjective. If it said only, "well might happen or be true", that definition is a verb, not an adjective. The phrase "such as" changes the verb phrase into an adjectival phrase. Consider:

> 1. An event well might happen or be true.
> 2. an event **such as** well might happen or be true

The first is a complete sentence, so "well might happen or be true" is a predicate, not an adjective. The second isn't a sentence, just a noun phrase where the noun "event" is modified by the adjectival phrase "such as well might happen or be true".

So in short, "such as" in a dictionary doesn't have any content, so you can skip it when reading.

Answer (score 4):

'Likely' describes the measurement of possibility that something could happen. It could be said to be somewhere between 'certain' and 'possible'.

- If something is *certain* to happen, you believe it *definitely will*.
- If something is *possible*, you believe it *could* happen, but may not. Something is 'possible' if it is *able* to happen, even when nothing is in place to make it so.
- If something is *likely* you believe there is a *strong chance* it will happen. You could say that the odds (or measurement of chance) of it happening are favourable.